# g:set tag inside template body in grails

Tags: grails, gsp

I using `<g:set>` tag inside `g:render` template body

```
<g:render template="/template/panelContainer">
  <g:set var="tomorrow" value="${new Date() + 1}"/>
  ${tomorrow}
</g:render>
```

_panelContainer.gsp:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
${raw(body())}
</div>
```

However `tomorrow` variable is not set. How do I need to implement template to properly execute `g:set` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<g:set var="tomorrow" value="${new Date() + 1}"/>
<g:render template="/template/panelContainer" model="${[tomorrow:tomorrow]}"/>
```

Comment: That's works, but I spent several hours trying to understand why <g:set> is not working inside template.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to set the variable before calling the render method.

```
<g:set var="tomorrow" value="${new Date() + 1}"/>
```

Then you can pass this variable in your template using the model attribute. Like:

```
<g:render template="/template/panelContainer" model="${[tomorrow:tomorrow]}"/>
```

The `body()` you are trying to use is used to pass along other body content to be displayed inside the template. Like:

```
<g:render template="/template/panelContainer" model="${[tomorrow:tomorrow]}">
  <a href="..">..</a>
</g:render>
```